# An "array" but with no limit on the rows or the columns

Tags: c#, arrays

So, this is for a task we received at school. The thing I need is the following:
When you select a customer from a listbox (lstCustomers), it should show all purchases they made, but you can also add a new purchase to that customer, so you don't have any clue how many purchases the customer will make, neither do you know how many customers will be in the listbox (lstCustomers), since you can also keep creating them. The thing I would want is that I would use the same index as the List I'm using for my customers in this "array", so that these are 'linked'.
What can I use to create this "array"/list/...

I've tried using 2D arrays (but of course, these are limited), I've tried using 2D lists but I couldn't get this to work the way I wanted. I've tried working with DataTable as well, but I'm not familiar with DataTable, so that wasn't really working out too.

Any solutions to this?

Attempts (recreated):

```
List<List<string>> Purchases = new List<List<string>>();
```

But at this I couldn't figure out how to get the purchase at the right column index, and at the first empty cell in the row.

After that I've tried adding multiple lists to the list after initializing the list, but this limits (as far as I could figure out) the amount of lists inside the list.

Array just didn't seem the right option since this is limited, and like I've mentioned, I'm not familiar to DataTable...

Comment: You can use a `List` or a `ObservableCollection` and call the `Add` method, for example.

Comment: Post what you've tried! :)

Comment: Sounds like you want a `List<Customer>` where the `Customer` has a `Purchases` property that is a `List<Purchases>`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a Customer class which has a list of purchases

```
public class Customer
{
    public List<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    //other properties eg. id, etc...
}
public class Purchase
{
    public string PurchaseName { get; set; }
    //other properties eg. id, etc...
}
```

Comment: This would probably work out perfectly when I would've been utilising props since the beginning, I got both classes already, but since this is litterally the first prop in my entire project now, I'm kinda screwed... Still thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it.